# Dynamic SVG animation only works once

Tags: javascript, dynamic, svg

I have this animation setup to indicate which `SVG` was selected. The animation adds a `svg:use` element, and 3 animate or `animateTransform` elements within the `svg:use` element. Thanks to some great help here on SO I was able to get this working properly.

My new problem however is that the animation only works once as designed once. If a second element is selected, the animation appears to try to take place, as you can see the stroke-width increase, but the scale doesn't happen.

I thought this would be a simple fix by using a `setTimeout` to call a function and remove the `svg:use` after the animation completed. I wasn't so lucky.

An example of my problem can be seen here: http://codepen.io/JoeyCinAZ/pen/GHhbw

The function I wrote to remove the animation is here

```
setTimeout( function() {removeAnimation(objID)}, 5000);

function removeAnimation(objID) {
    var useEl = document.getElementById(objID);
    useEl.nextSibling.remove();
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Also, you should remove the anony function: `setTimeout( removeAnimation.bind(this, objID), 5000);`

Comment: No, no errors are being logged. And are you saying to replace the anonymous function with the one in your comment?

Comment: yes, its just cleaner way to do the exact same thing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've two issues within the animation. The simplest is duration, it can't per the SVG specification begin with a . so

```
 flash.setAttributeNS(null, 'dur', '.5s');
```

is strictly speaking not valid and Firefox rejects it. I believe there are plans to change the SVG specification to match Chrome's laxer behaviour but until that happens write it as

```
 flash.setAttributeNS(null, 'dur', '0.5s');
```

Secondly your main issue is that once you run the animation the document timeline goes from 0 to 5.5 seconds (that's how long all your animations take). The next time you create the animation, the document timeline is therefore at 5.5 seconds and the initial animation doesn't run because it's in the past as it's supposed to start at 0s. You could solve this either by

a) calling [setCurrentTime](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#__svg__SVGSVGElement__setCurrentTime) to reset the timeline to 0, or

b) having the initial animation trigger from the button press event.

Comment: Robert, your knowledge of SVGs is astonishing. Thank you. I used the setCurrentTime method, and things are running very smoothly now.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue before and solved it by completely removing the content of the element that contains the generated SVG, and then simply reload the new SVG in the empty element.

Instead of using a `setTimeout` which make the whole thing a bit weird, I would simply call it on clicking the element selector:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('myElementSelector');

elem.addEventListener('click', function() {  
   document.getElementById(surroundingElementID).innerHTML = "";
   //Check what has been clicked and call function that creates the SVG on the surroundingElementID
}, false);
```